# Python - Writing and continuously updating a file

Tags: python, linux

I have the following code to write data into a file continuously:

```
matrix=open("matrix.txt","r+")
i=0
while i<100:
    for row in range(10):
        matrix.write('\n')
        for column in range(10):
            matrix.truncate()
            matrix.write(str(i))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            i+=1
matrix.close()
```

It is working, but in order for me to view the updated data, I have to reload the file every time by clicking on the reload button when my OS (linux) tells me the file has changed, is there a way for it to update and continuously show the updated file with each iteration without me having to click the button?

Comment: That's just how your file viewing app is implemented. Sublime Text for example loads the updated file without asking

Comment: @Vall3y Thank you for your answer, but even with sublime, i have to refresh the file manually by clicking another file and clicking it again :/

Answer (score 2):

Try `tail -f matrix.txt` in a terminal.